# Как я могу реализовать алгоритм глубокого копирования без использования JSON.parse и JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript

```
let user = {
  name: "John",
  age: 30
};

let clone = Object.assign({}, user);
```

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) на самом деле быстрее копирует обьекты чем все эти Object.assign. Ну а так то в цикле делать Object.assign

Comment: ок но есть другой метод без использования JSON.parse и JSON.stringify??

Comment: Есть метод: не меняйте объекты, создавайте новые; у вас еще и сравнения будут лучше работать; `setState(was => ({...was, key: value}))`; есть и библиотеки на тему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовать например самому глубокое копирование как указано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

```js
function cloneSO(obj) {
        // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
        if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    
        // Handle Array
        if (obj instanceof Array) {
            var copy = [];
            for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
                copy[i] = cloneSO(obj[i]);
            }
            return copy;
        }
    
        // Handle Object
        if (obj instanceof Object) {
            var copy = {};
            for (var attr in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = cloneSO(obj[attr]);
            }
            return copy;
        }
    
        throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
    }
    
    let user = {
      name: "John",
      age: 30
   };
   
   let userCopy = cloneSO(user);
   
   console.log(userCopy, user, userCopy === user);
```

Comment: пора расширять метод, сейчас им уже не все объекты можно скопировать, например `Map` нельзя, а так же Set тоже. Хотя и `JSON.stringify`  с ними тоже не справляется

Comment: @Grundy звучит как бы каждый класс пусть сам реализует clone универсальный слишком сложный

Comment: В большинстве случаев клонирование и не нужно

Comment: @Grundy мне в практике за 17 лет всего один раз пригодился и тот поверхностный глубокий не пригодился и вовсе.

Comment: Как правило `Object.assign` хватает

Comment: Согласен, тут спорить не очем